# How to make a global keyboard hook in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, electron.net

How can I make a global keyboard hook for an Electron.NET app in C#? I believe as long as it works in a console app it should work properly in an Electron.Net app.

I made a 'solution' for this problem, but It tends to use up a lot of CPU (7-10%). Maybe someone is somehow able to make it actually efficient if there is no other option:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey);

// Other VKey codes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes
public enum VKeys {
    LBUTTON = 0x01,     // Left mouse button
    RBUTTON = 0x02,     // Right mouse button
    KEY_0 = 0x30,       // 0 key
    KEY_1 = 0x31,       // 1 key
    KEY_2 = 0x32,       // 2 key
    KEY_3 = 0x33,       // 3 key
    KEY_4 = 0x34,       // 4 key
    KEY_5 = 0x35,       // 5 key
    KEY_6 = 0x36,       // 6 key
    KEY_7 = 0x37,       // 7 key
    KEY_8 = 0x38,       // 8 key
    KEY_9 = 0x39        // 9 key
}

public void Start()
{
    Thread HookThread = new Thread(delegate ()
    {
        var keys = Enum.GetValues(typeof(VKeys));

        while (true)
        {
            foreach (int key in keys)
            {
                var ks = GetAsyncKeyState(key);

                if (ks < 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"pressed {key}");
                    //Thread.Sleep(100);
                }

                //Thread.Sleep(1); // Even sleeping for '1ms' will delay it too much
            }
        }
    });

    HookThread.Start();
}
```

A lot of things I found would only work if I was using WinForms or WPF.

**Edit:**

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61567738/13054237) answer by hanabanashiku, and a lot of others that I found online, but all of them seemed to just lag the keyboards input and their callback functions would seem to be never called.

I decided to write the keyboard hook in C++, compile as a DLL and then reference that DLL in my C# code to hopefully make a keyboard hook that functioned properly and didn't cause any noticeable input lag, but that didn't work either.

The keyboard hook ran perfectly when run as an .exe in C++, but when I compiled it as a DLL and ran it in C# it caused the same issue as before - a lot of input lag and the callback function seemingly not being called.

Heres the code if anyone wants to try it:

**KeyboardHook.cpp**

```
#include "KeyboardHook.h"
#include <iostream>

#define __event void KeyDown(int key), KeyUp(int key);

using namespace Hooks;

void KeyDown(int key)
{
    std::cout << "KeyDown\n";
}

void KeyUp(int key)
{
    std::cout << "KeyUp\n";
}

LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT p = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam;

        switch (wParam)
        {
            case WM_KEYDOWN:
            case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
                KeyDown(p->vkCode);
                break;
            case WM_KEYUP:
            case WM_SYSKEYUP:
                KeyUp(p->vkCode);
                break;
        }
    }

    // Not processing keys so always return CallNextHookEx
    return(CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam));
}

void KeyboardHook::Install() {
    // Install keyboard hook
    keyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardProc, 0, 0);
    std::cout << "Installed\n";
}

void KeyboardHook::Uninstall() {
    // Unhook keyboard hook
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(keyboardHook);
}
```

**KeyboardHook.h**

```
#include <Windows.h>

HHOOK keyboardHook;

namespace Hooks 
{
    class KeyboardHook
    {
    public:
        __declspec(dllexport) void Install();
        __declspec(dllexport) void Uninstall();
    };
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace HelloMyNameIsSpindiNiceToMeetYou
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string hooksPath = @"C:\Path\To\Hooks.dll";

        // If EntryPoint doesn't work, yours might be different
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/identifying-functions-in-dlls
        //
        // "For example, you can use dumpbin /exports Hooks.dll [...] to obtain function names." 
        // you need to be in the folder with the dll for above to work in Command Prompt for VS
        [DllImport(hooksPath, EntryPoint = "?Install@KeyboardHook@Hooks@@QEAAXXZ", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private extern static void Install();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Install();

            // keep console app running
            while (true)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // or keep it running with this
            // Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I am testing this stuff outside of an electron.net app now, just in a console app and things still don't work. Everything I have found just leads back to using winforms, which I cannot use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electron has a way to create [global shortcuts](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/global-shortcut) built-in, you just have to adapt the syntax a little to work with Electron.Net, you can search the [repo](https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET) to figure out function names (usually names are the same, just in PascalCase).

Registering a shortcut:

```
Electron.GlobalShortcut.Register("CommandOrControl+X", () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("CommandOrControl+X pressed");
});
```

Unregistering a shortcut:

```
// Unregister specific shortcut
Electron.GlobalShortcut.Unregister("CommandOrControl+X");

// Unregister all shortcuts
Electron.GlobalShortcut.UnregisterAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution uses a lot of computing power, because every time the loop repeats, it's making 11 calls to the Windows API. To more efficiently accomplish this, you will want to add a keyboard [hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/hooks). A simple solution would be something like the following.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);


private static InPtr hook_ = IntPtr.Zero;
private static LowLevelHookProc _proc = KeyboardProc;

public void Start() {
    using (var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (var module = process.MainModule)
        {
            _hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, _proc,
                GetModuleHandle(module.ModuleName), 0);
        }

private static IntPtr KeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN) {
            switch(nCode) {
                 // Look for keys
            }
        }

        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

The Callback function will fire every time a key is pressed down. Simply look for the virtual keys that you wish to query.

Comment: Is it possible you show me how you are using this code? I am calling the Start() function in a test console app and added keys to the switch statement (with each key there is a console.writeline). Nothing is being written to the console, but it is laggy for the keys that I press to come up when I type somewhere, so it's doing something, but I don't know what.

Comment: Once you set the hook, the system will call the keyboard pros function every time there is a key event. You can check which key is being pressed using the nCode parameter compared with the list of virtual keys you had previously. In the start you would right the hook and in the hook function you would write the print to terminal.

Comment: I put a console.writeline in the KeyboardProc function, but it never gets run.